# Proof of existence of prefix in NFA

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

Let $$A= (Q,Σ,δ,s,F)$$ be a NFA. Prove the following statement:

$∀q ∈ Q: (∃ w_2 ∈ Σ^* :δ (q, w_2) ∩ F \ne  ∅ ⇒ ∃w_1 ∈ Σ^*:w_1w_2 ∈ L(A))$

I figured out that it means that if all the states have a path to the final state, that the **word** describing their path is a suffix of a word that is accepted from the NEA.

The thing is: How can I be sure that the NEA accepts all words with that suffix if it doesn't start from the **s** state.

Any leads?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the statement correctly? We cannot help you otherwise.

Comment: It's absolutely correct.

Comment: What's a NEA?  Did you mean NFA?

Comment: Yes. I meant NFA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. Consider the NFA on the alphabet $\{a\}$ having two states: an initial state $q_0$, and the unique final state $q_f$. The transition function is given by $\delta(q_0,a) = \{q_0\}$ and $\delta(q_f,a) = \{q_f\}$. For every word $w_2$ it is the case that $\delta(q_f,w_2) \cap F = \emptyset$, yet $w_1 w_2 \notin L(A)$ for all $w_1$.

Comment: It has to be true for all words starting from q_0 too. 
In this case there isn't a word w_2 for q_0 with which we end up in a final state.

Comment: You're confusing the order of quantifiers. The statement claims that for all states $q$, something is true. That something is that there exists a word $w_2$ so that the following holds: if $\delta(q,w_2) \cap F \neq \emptyset$ then there exists a word $w_1$ such that $w_1w_2 \in L(A)$.

Comment: I show that this statement is false for my NFA, by showing that it is false for the state $q_f$.

Comment: This leads me to believe that you either copies the statement wrong, or forgot to include the assumption that all states are reachable from the initial state.

Comment: I see what I've missed. I didn't get the quantifiers wrong, I just misinterpreted the implication. I assumed that it should be true for all states that they can reach the final state. The thing is that it must hold true **only** for states that DO end up in final states. Anyway thanks for the quick response as always :)